# Check if a string is valid BSON in python

Tags: python, bson

The way I used to do this was to run this function

```
import bson 

def has_binary(d):
if type(d)==bson.Binary:
    return True
if type(d)==dict:
    for k,v in d.iteritems():
        if has_binary(v):
            return True
return False
```

This no longer works, because the bson library has no attribute 'binary'

Comment: Are you sure it's not supposed to be [`bson.binary.Binary`](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/bson/binary.html#bson.binary.Binary)?

Comment: Yep. That throws the same error. It's this library https://github.com/py-bson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you appear to be using a 3rd party py-bson, perhaps due to `pip install bson`.

https://github.com/py-bson

rather than mongodb supported python-bson `pip install pymongo`.

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/tree/master/bson

Note install:

> PyMongo can be installed with pip:
>
> $ python -m pip install pymongo
>
> **Do not install the “bson” package**. PyMongo comes with its own bson
>   package; doing “easy_install bson” installs a third-party package that
>   is incompatible with PyMongo.

You can either switch to the mongodb version of bson and your function will simply work, or change your is_binary function to accommodate the fact that pybson decodes everything to strings in python2 and bytes in python3.

https://github.com/py-bson/bson/blob/master/bson/codec.py#L303-L307